# Set up an integral for the arc length

Tags: calculus, arc-length

I am struggling with a task.

The equation$$(x-y)^2 + 4(x+y)^2 = 1$$represent a conic section and I have to set up an integral for the arc length og the conic section. But I am not sure how to set it up. Im not sure but I think the arc length formula is

$$S = \int \sqrt{(1 + (f’(x))^2}  \,\mathrm{d}x,$$

and this is where I am confused. Am I thinking right? If I am, then $f'(x) = 20x+6$ and all I have to do is to put $f'(x)$ in the formula.

Comment: What is your $f(x)$ ? Did you get it by solving the equation for $y$ ?

Comment: There isnt any f(x), this is why I am confused

Comment: Why did you write $f'(x) = 20x+6$?

Comment: Deleting a question after an answer has been provided is not really fair. Once a question has been asked (and answered) it becomes part of the community resources.

Comment: Additionally, please clarify what the $20x+6$ has to do with the initial ellipse.

Answer (score 2):

The locus of $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$$(x-y)^2+4(x+y)^2 = 1 $$
is isometric to the locus of $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$$ 2x^2+8y^2 = 1 $$
i.e. to an ellipse with semi-axis lenghts $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$.
 
To compute its perimeter it is more practical to employ the formula for the length of parametric curves (rather than the formula for the length of a graph, since an ellipse is not globally a graph) and symmetry:
$$ L = 4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\sin^2\theta+\frac{1}{8}\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta=2\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\frac{3}{4}\cos^2\theta}\,d\theta =\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{4-3t^2}{1-t^2}}\,dt$$
This is a [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html). The numerical evaluation of such objects is an interesting topic, I suggest you to have a look at the dedicated section in [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view) (elliptic integrals and the AGM). A practical approximation, which is also pretty accurate for ellipses with a not too large eccentricity, is the following one (due to Muir):

> The perimeter of an ellipse with semi-axis lengths $a,b$ is approximately
>   $$ 2\pi\left(\frac{a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}}{2}\right)^{2/3}.$$

In your case Muir's approximation returns a $\color{green}{3.42}475\ldots$ while the actual perimeter is $\color{green}{3.425383717962}\ldots$. The error is less than 2 parts in 10 thousands.